# Git pull request - how to pull and update Sublime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I've made a stupid error which has messed up my database on a Rails App I'm working on. Luckily I'm on a branch and haven't committed any changes so the version on Git is in working order.

How do I now pull through the Git version and update to Sublime so I can carry on working as if nothing happened? 
I've just done git pull origin master but it says up to date so I've obviously done something wrong. 
I'm not keen on a db:drop so I'd rather do it this way if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pull again, because you already pulled every commit from your remote.

Add changes, stash them, remove the stash:

```
git add --all && git stash && git stash drop
```

This will remove every uncommited change and bring you back to the latest commit on the current branch.

Comment: How do you pull this back into sublime? Do you just open up Sublime again on the command line?

Comment: Sublime should automatically show the updated state from the file system

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout 01h5y77d (find this in git, a version of the app which works)
```

This would print "HEAD is now at 01h5y77d..." 
You don't have to commit because you did not commit the mistakes yet :)

Comment: So, what does this do?